# Kotlin + Arrow-kt - why are my coroutines not cancelling properly?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation, arrow-kt

I am using Kotlin together with Arrow-Kt libraries.
I am launching on a specific scope some coroutines that make use of Arrow-kt's Schedule.

At a certain time, I want to be able to cancel all those coroutines that were launched on that scope, but after I cancel the scope basically nothing changes and whatever was running on the Schedule, continues to run, which is not what I wanted.

I already tried to place some yield() calls to force the coroutines to be cancellable, but the behavior didn't change.

Here is the code:

Main function doing the launches:

```
    private val ballFetchingScope= CoroutineScope(CoroutineName("ball-fetching"))
    fun fetchBalls(periodicity: Periodicity) {
        val balls = stockRepository.getAllBalls() //basically a list of different balls

        balls.forEach {
                ballFetchingScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ballFetcher.startFetching(it, periodicity) }
        }
    }
```

startFetching function, using Arrow-kt's schedule:

```
    suspend fun startFetching(ball: Ball, periodicity: Periodicity) {

        Schedule.forever<Unit>()
            .and(Schedule.spaced(periodicity))
            .repeat {
                yield()
                //ball fetching logic here
            }
    }
```

**Expected behavior:**

When calling `ballFetchingScope.cancel()` all coroutines are cancelled and all fetching stops.
Ideally not even needing to wait until it reaches the yield() call, if it is waiting for the next run to happen, I would like for it to cancel and not even start a new run of the repeat block.

**What is actually happening:**

Fetching continues to happen normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to say here what is going on.

It's very strange that this is not working for you, since `Schedule` relies on KotlinX *kotlin.coroutines.delay* to execute the `Schedule.spaced`. So it should get cancelled while *waiting for the next run*.

It also checks `coroutineContext.ensureActive()` before running the function passed to `repeat` so it also automatically check in the place where you now manually placed *yield*.

Which version of Arrow are you using? And could you share a fully reproducible example?

Comment: Thank you for helping, I'll share a working example when I am back home, in the afternoon

Comment: while arranging a working example to share with you, I noticed that I was messing up. 
I had two different instances of the class containing the scope, meaning, I had two different scopes. 

I was cancelling on one, while the other was the one where the actual fetching was running. 

Sorry for wasting your time mate! Thank you once again.

Comment: My pleasure, glad you were able to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own post just to make sure you are not making the same dumb mistake I was making.

Everything was working as supposed, the issue was on my side.
I had two different instances of the class containing the `ballFetchingScope`

This means that I was calling the `ballFetchingScope.cancel()` on the scope for one of those instances while the Coroutines were running on the scope in the other instance.

Botom-line: Make sure you are not using multiple instances when you think you have only one.